# Can't add masonry to symfony 6 webpack-encore project

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, jquery-masonry, webpack-encore

I'm working on a symfony 6 project and i'm trying to use webpack encore to add masonry grid.

I'm using this documentation : [masonry.desandro.com](https://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html)

I'm using yarn to add masonry-layout

```
yarn add masonry-layout
```

my webpack config :

```
...
.autoProvideVariables({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
})
```

My app.js

```
// You can specify which plugins you need
import 'bootstrap';
// import { Tooltip, Toast, Popover } from 'bootstrap';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';

const $ = require('jquery');

import * as masonry from 'masonry-layout';

$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 160
});
```

My index.html.twig

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
</div>
```

I'm always getting this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: r(...)(...).masonry is not a function

How can i correctly add masonry using webpack ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> To use Masonry as a jQuery plugin with Webpack, you need to use jQuery Bridget

See: https://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html